# how do you run a program in the terminal

Tags: command-line

I have to open a program called Vbox, and some other specific programs related to that.There is also a program called libquantum. however these programs have to be run from a terminal. what is the specific command and syntax to run these programs? I do not have much experience with an ubuntu terminal.

Comment: Googling for libquantum it seems like it's a C library for quantum physics simulation... so you don't run it. It's not a program, it's a set of functions that will help you code your own simulations (that will be compiled and then ran). I may be wrong, though.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu, and other Linux systems, have a terminal that generally uses this syntax:

```
COMMAND [OPTIONS] [ARGUMENTS..]
```

For instance, copy, or `cp`. If you were to do this command:

```
cp -r folder1 Documents/folder2
```

Which would:

- `cp` - the 'copy' command
- `-r` - the recursive option, used on folders
- `folder1 Documents/folder2` - the arguments, which are the source folder, and the destination folder.

Simple ;-)

You can also autocomplete commands, using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. If you were to type:

```
apt-g
```

and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```
apt-get
```

it should autocomplete the command. In this case the command is `VBoxManage`. There are tutorials on it [here](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/06/how-to-use-virtualbox-in-terminal-commandline/) and [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-control-virtual-machines-virtualbox-using-vboxmanage.html). Here is one example:

```
VBoxManage startvm "Windows XP"
```

which would start the Windows XP virtual machine, if it existed.

To install libquantam, you should be able to use:

```
sudo apt-get install libquantum
```

if that does not work, try:
    sudo apt-get install libquantum-dev
    sudo apt-get install libquantum*

Answer (score 1):

1- VBox use `VBoxManage` command
and need to pass parameters as your needs for example

```
VBoxManage createhd --filename Ubuntu10.10 --size 5120
```

[for more detail](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/06/how-to-use-virtualbox-in-terminal-commandline/)

sorry I don't know about `libquantum`